# Do actions that are not defined in the controller need authorization such as before_action nevertheless?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-4, authorization

My `UsersController` does not have the actions `destroy`, `index` and `show` defined, as they won't be needed. I'll delete users out of the database and a users page or a user index page won't be available in the application.

However, is it necessary to secure those actions nonetheless with a filter such as `before_action :correct_user` to provide maximum security or is there no way a potential attacker could somehow manipulate actions in order to view or destroy users?

Besides that, does a create and new action of a `PostsController` need to be protected by a filter as well? Read: Is it possible for people with too much time on their hands to create posts with the ID of other users?

Also, what are some ways to make sure all actions are bulletproof? I am currently using TDD for this -- any alternatives?

I am rather new to authorization and security – are there any good resources on this topic? Books, articles, screencasts will do.

Comment: a reference book for many rails beginners: https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: Igor, certainly aware of railstutorial and been through the whole book. It is where I picked up TDD and therefore can recommend it to everyone who is not familiar with TDD yet. Other resources would be appreciated.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/straightforward-rails-authorization-with-pundit/ and on this site you'll find other topics about authorization and not only

Answer (score 0):

You can just restrict your resource routes so that those actions are not available.

Full details are available in the routing guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created

Something like this would do it:

```
resources :users, except: [:index, :show, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have not defined those actions, your controller will not do anything, except trying to render the corresponding view templates (e.g. `app/views/users/show.html.erb`), which should not exist if you do not need them.

While I do not see security concerns, it is better not to create routes for actions that are not defined: if the routes exist, the action is not defined, and the view template does not exist, your users will get an HTTP status 500 (internal server error), instead of the correct status 404 (not found). If you are using `resources` in your routes.rb file, you should exclude the actions that you do not need:

```
resources :users, except: [:destroy, :index, :show]
```

Regarding your `PostsController`, you should always create objects as the `current_user`, and ignore whatever user id an attacker might add to the parameters of the request. If you are using strong parameters, there is no reason to even have `user_id` in the permitted parameters.

You should also check that a user is signed in whenever necessary; if you are managing authentication with devise, that would be `before_action :authenticate_user!`: this will redirect the user to the sign in page when they try to access a protected action without signing in first.

My favorite book on testing (with RSpec) is [Everyday Rails Testing with RSpec](https://leanpub.com/everydayrailsrspec).